# to warn somebody using a conditional sentence

Tags: grammar

If we have to warn someone of something horrible that is REAL (i.e. that exists) and may appear but we are mentioning it just to make that person realize its horror. Our statement is just for making them understand that they must be careful or change their conduct. It is not usual to appear but may appear. Which conditional will we use?

A. If the hell opens its gate, things will burn.

B. If the hell opened its gate, things would burn.

C. If the hell were to open its gate, things would burn.

Comment: not *the* hell. Treat it as a proper noun  "if Hell opens...

Comment: The other problem in this question is you say "is REAL" but then give an example that is supernatural.  Should we consider Hell opening its gate to be a literal possibility, and not a metaphor.  Should we not consider it to be a future certainty?

Comment: Actually, the situation is that A is making B assume it and take a caution. He is certain that Hell can open its gate but not saying that 'it is going to'.

Comment: *If the hell opens its gate...* isn't natural phrasing in English. A common alternative might be [*If the gates of Hell open...*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22If+the+gates+of+Hell+open%22)

Answer (score 1):

The first and the second are the usual "first and second conditional"

> "If Hell opens"....  (A condition I think is likely to occur)

> "If Hell opened"... (A condition I think is unlikely to occur)

These are fairly neutral in their attitude towards Hell.

The third is used if the conditional form is unthinkably horrible.  This fits well with the idea of "Hell".

If you think that Hell will open its gates then use "When"

> When Hell opens its gates  (A condition that is almost certain to occur)

I'd probably use the "were to" form, for the "horrible" nuance.

Answer (score 0):

Well you've used a metaphor rather than something real. Hell is a supernatural/mythological concept and so Hell will not 'open its gates' in reality. Also the expression 'if Hell opens its gates' is quite clumsy and they are usually referred to in fiction as 'the gates of Hell' e.g. "Open the gates of Hell and let loose the demons!"

But in terms of which conditional you use, it's all depends upon whether or not the outcome is certain or uncertain - "If you operate electric devices in the bath and they fall in, you will get electrocuted and may die!", "Run into the road without looking, and you might get run over and killed", "If you do a parachute jump and your parachute fail to open, you would be killed".